# How do content attributes and IDL attributes interact?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, idl

I am trying to understand the short [entry on IDL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IDL) in the MDN Glossary.

In particular, I am struggling with the behavior described in the 4th paragraph under the "Content versus IDL attributes" header.

> Most of the time, IDL attributes will return their values as they are really used. For example, the default `type` for `<input>` elements is "text", so if you set `input.type="foobar"`, the `<input>` element will be of type text (in the appearance and the behavior) but the "type" content attribute's value will be "foobar". However, the `type` IDL attribute will return the string `"text"`.

I will list a series of questions, along with my current 'informed guesses' in bulletpoints. I would like to either confirm my understanding, or expose my lack of it. Any input, clarification, or critique is appreciated (the questions may be fully off-base).

---

What does 'their values as they are really used' mean in this context (their default value [e.g, "text"], or the value set in a specific context [e.g, "foobar"])?

- default (in the example, "test") - hence the final sentence of the quote.

Is the `<input>` element's type an IDL or content attribute?

- (technically both? but inasmuch as we access it through `input.type` it is an) IDL attribute

If IDL attributes are set using `element.foo`, doesn't `input.type` qualify as setting an IDL attribute (in which case the "type" content attribute should *not* be `"foobar"`)?

- This misses a key behavior of IDL attributes w.r.t. content attributes: content atttributes can be *set* through IDL attributes, while leaving the IDL attribute itself unchanged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What does 'their values as they are really used' mean in this context (their default value [e.g, "text"], or the value set in a specific context [e.g, "foobar"])?

The `type` isn't just a field to store some value, right? It's an important characteristic of the `<input />` element and should be understood and used by the browser. Browser will render different control and/or it's behavior depending on that field (compare `<input type="text" />`, `<input type="file" />`, `<input type="date" />`).

Having variety of browsers with different feature sets, they're not stopping working when receive unknown values. In case of input's `type` attribute, they will just fallback to the `text` when given value is unknown.

So `text` will be the *really used* one, while `foobar` is still stored as it was originally set and can be accessed via `attributes`.

> Is the  element's type an IDL or content attribute?

You're right, it's both: IDL and content attribute, depending on how it is accessed. It stores the original value and you can access it via `element.attributes['type']` and you can get actual (working / supported) value via IDL.

> If IDL attributes are set using element.foo, doesn't input.type qualify as setting an IDL attribute (in which case the "type" content attribute should not be "foobar")?

It is, but IDL attribute isn't just a box where you can put whatever you want. It will take your value, store to the attributes dictionary and try to use with various validations and fallbacks. In case it can't use that value, it will use one of the fallback options it finds the best.

Comment: cheers. to reiterate a couple things: (1) regardless of if the value is supported, any set value is stored in the `attributes` property of the corresponding DOM object? (2) if we instead use `input.type="file"`, should we expect to see the IDL attribute change properly to "file" (as opposed to "foobar" which is invalid and leaves the IDL attribute as the default "text")? (3) the `attributes` property of a DOM object does *not* have entries corresponding to their IDL attributes? (can we 'get' an IDL attribute?)

Comment: @shea (1) yes (2) absolutely. If you set some valid value (e.g. `input.type = "file"`) you'll see it via both content and IDL attributes. And when you set something invalid it will **set** it to the default, not **leave** as is. So if `input` had `type="file"` and you set it to `foobar`, accessing `input.type` you'll get `text`, not `file`. (3) `attributes` is how you can access content attributes, they represent what was set to the element. `<input />` won't have anything in `attributes`, but you can get any of IDL (e.g. `input.type` will still return the default `text`).